# Android speech To Text Handling

Tags: android

in softkeyboard i have the option for speech to text , when i spoke it show a list of suggestion , when i select a text ,i need to fill my editText with this text, how can i done this i have see SpeechRecognizer class ,i don't know how can i use this ,please help me

```
SpeechRecognizer rec=SpeechRecognizer.createSpeechRecognizer(context);

        RecognitionListener listener = new RecognitionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onRmsChanged(float rmsdB) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onResults(Bundle results) {
                ArrayList<String> voiceResults = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);


            }

            @Override
            public void onReadyForSpeech(Bundle params) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onPartialResults(Bundle partialResults) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onEvent(int eventType, Bundle params) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onError(int error) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onEndOfSpeech() {


            }

            @Override
            public void onBufferReceived(byte[] buffer) {


            }

            @Override
            public void onBeginningOfSpeech() {


            }
        };
        rec.setRecognitionListener(listener);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your text edit is named "te":

```
public void onResults(Bundle results) {   
  ArrayList<String> voiceResults = results.getStringArrayList(SpeechRecognizer.RESULTS_RECOGNITION);
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for(String p: voiceResults)   {
    sb.append(p);
    sb.append("\n");   }   te.setText(sb.toString()); 
  }
```

Normally, you are only interested in the first result (i.e voiceResults (0)) since that is the most probable match but the code above shows all of them so you can see what is returned.