# Android Speech to Text

Tags: android, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I have Table which contain the products.

```
  ProductCode  ProductName  Qty  Price
  0001           AAAA       10   100.00
```

Like wise i have it.The `Qty` is the `EditText`. User need to enter the quantity.

In here, for example user say 10 then it should enter 10 into that particular EditText. How we can do this. This is my image:

[image]

Please help me how we can do this? Is there any idea?

I have looked this forums
[Text To Speech In android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6222823/text-to-speech-in-android)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608236/text-to-speech-frequency-problem-in-android
[Android speech To Text Handling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177432/android-speech-to-text-handling)

& want to know is it the performance issue? that means enter the text take some times?

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything. The user can tap the open editText area, then click the microphone icon to start speech recognition.

If you want a specialized button or other way to put the input in, you'll need code like this:

https://github.com/gmilette/Say-the-Magic-Word-

Answer (score 2):

In terms of performance there is no issue but `TTS` requires too much time first it will listen the voice analyze it and if analyzed correctly then fill up and this whole process is lengthy enough.

Apart from that user have to put concentration on his/her speech which really pain for end user